# Get apache2 load new PHP5

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, ubuntu-9.04

This server is running ubuntu 9.04, apache 2 and running running PHP 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.4 from the repository. I installed another a new version of PHP (5.3.1, compiled from source), I then replaced the link of this version with /usr/bin/php5. Now cli loads the new version

```
name:/$php -v
PHP 5.3.1 (cli) (built: Dec 9 2009 21:44:18 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

However, apache still loads the old version. What should I do to get apache load the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/usr/bin/php(5) is only used by the CLI version of PHP.

On Ubuntu Apache loads its PHP from /etc/apache2/mods-{available,enabled}/php5.load. What you need is to disabled that loading and instead load your own libphp5.so.